# pg_restore: error: could not execute query: ERROR: materialized view "ws1_all_formate" has not been populated

Tags: postgresql, errors, pg-dump, pg-restore

I had this error after the execution of `pg_restore`:

```
pg_restore: finished item 19181 MATERIALIZED VIEW DATA avenant_f
pg_restore: from TOC entry 19171; 0 2565914 MATERIALIZED VIEW DATA conf_j2_par_plaque Administrateur
pg_restore: error: could not execute query: ERROR:  materialized view "ws1_all_formate" has not been populated
HINT:  Use the REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW command.
Command was: REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW conf_j2_par_plaque;
```

[image]

Is it a serious error? Do I have to redo the restore operation?

Answer (score 1):

If that's all the feedback you got, just execute on the advice from the error message:

```
REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW conf_j2_par_plaque;
```

The way I read it, Postgres could not execute that command as planned, because  another materialized view `"ws1_all_formate"` had not been populated yet. So the MV at hand  (which seems to rely on it) was created, but not populated, yet.

But your image (which should be text) says:

> pg_restore: warning: errors ignored on restore: 663

I would first investigate that number of ignored errors ...